# Hide tab bar issues in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am facing issues when hiding the bottom uiTabBar Controller.I am using the following code to hide.

```
 UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UIView *parent = tabBar.superview;
UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *window = parent.superview;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                     tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds);
                     tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
                     content.frame = window.bounds;
                 }];
```

Its working fine.But in the main view i am having button and user clicks the button it opens the modal view controller as  popup dialog.After cancel the pop up dialog the following screen will appear.

[image]

Comment: are you using navigationcontroller in your app

Comment: @CharanGiri Yes i am navigation controller too.

Comment: Please give me solution for that issues.I am really looking forward

Comment: are you facing problem for status bar?? is status bar overlapping??

Comment: Can you just select "Hides bottom bar when pushed" option in story board for that view controller?

Comment: self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Comment: Where to add this line self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES; in viewDidLoad()

Comment: @CharanGiri its not working self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Comment: in your first screen it will not work because the property is like once you navigate to any screen it will hide the tabbar

Comment: @CharanGiri No i am not using navigation controller in my app.I just want to hide the bottom tab bar when user selects the second tab bar item

Comment: tabBarObject.hidden=YES; try this

Answer (score 1):

Yes I solved my problem

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{

```
// Get the size of the main screen
CGRect fullScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

// Hide the tab bar
((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.hidden = YES;

// Resize and fill the screen
[[((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:fullScreenRect];
```

}

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

    ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).tabBar.hidden = NO;

}
```

When i am using the above code,It will work perfect :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller for which you want to hide tab bar & Check 'Hide bottom bar on push'.
[image]

Comment: Did u remove your earlier code (the one u posted)? because it works just fine for me.

Comment: No i want to use this code because when user clicks the tabbar item i want to hide the bottom tab bar.So only i cant remove my codes